# Calculating confidence intervals for product of $n$ different bernoulli trials with uncertain probabilities $p$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a process that basically consists of $n$ Bernoulli trials (each trial $T_i, i \in \{1,...,n\}$ can result in a pass/fail mark with associated likelihood of succes $p_i$), and need to find the likelihood *and associated confidence interval* that at least one trial results in a fail. The trials basically occurr at the same moment in time and can be considered independent.

For the likelihood not including the confidence interval, I figure:

$$P(T_i=1)=p_i$$
$$P(T_i=0)=1-p_i$$
$$P(\text{at least one fail})=1-\prod_{i=1}^{n} 1-p_i$$

Now, the issue I have is that each $p_i$ is estimated based on historic data. As such, they have an associated uncertainty. I have the number of historically carried out trials and successes for each $T_i$. While this means I can estimate the uncertainty (confidence interval) of each $p_i$ (I did that using a Beta distribution to do a maximum-likelihood estimation), I can't wrap my head around how this uncertainty propagates when combining the trials as described.

I considered using a Beta-binominal distribution, where my number of trials would be $n$, but the problem I have is that this distribution requires drawing from the *same* Beta-distributed variable, whereas my $p_i$ are estimates based on *different* ones.

Any help is greatly appreciated!